# setup wifi hotspot with 4G hat

Tags: wifi, hotspot, hat, bridge, modem

I have bought a 4G hat for my raspberry pi 3B+ (the sim7600 waveshare for europe) and followed [these](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=224355) instructions for setup. It is running the latest version of raspbian and I have internet on the raspberry through the USB interface (wwan0), which works perfectly.

However the next step for me is to setup a wifi hotspot and forward internet to other raspberry pi zeros. I followed [setting up hotspot](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) and similar posts [like this](https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/setting-up-a-wireless-access-point-a-bridge-method-internet-over-wired-ethernet) or [this](https://raspberrypihq.com/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-wifi-router/) but they all (most) involve ethernet connection. Also, documentation on configuring wwan0 for dhcpcd and dnsmasq or bridging that I could find are not very comprehensive.

I am relatively new and I got stuck in ip table rules and bridges and unable to setup for wwan0. Does somebody know how I should go about this?

Many thanks!

*I hope that I have all the relevant configuration files here.

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug wwan0
iface wwan0 inet manual #could not start with static

allow hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual #same, fails if I substitute with static keyword
    address 192.168.4.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.24.1.255
    broadcast 192.24.1.255
```

/etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
interface-wlan0
dhcp-range=192.168.4.2,192.168.4.20,255.255.255.0,24h
```

/etc/dhcpcd.conf

```
interface wlan0
    static ip_adress=192.168.4.1/24
    nohook wpa_supplicant
```

/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=MyId
hw_mode=g
channel=7
wmm_enabled=1
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_passphrase=password
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Comment: You posted a link to a tutorial, but seemed to have ignored the settings!

Comment: Sorry, could you maybe clarify which settings do you think are causing the problems? I assume /etc/network/interfaces file? I posted three tutorials because I followed several and combinations unsuccesfully.

Comment: There are so many inconsistencies just one `denyinterfaces wlan0 … interface wlan0` is nonsense. If you randomly mix different unreferenced tutorials you can't expect anyone to debug the mess.

Comment: I understand, and your right, only what I really need is some guidence how to forward internet to the created wifi hotspot. Because [raspberry documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) I can follow untill "Add routing and masquerade" and I seem to only find examples and no documentation about bridging. I included all this code because I dont know what I need to do

Comment: Welcome. Replacing "raspberry pi" with "linux" in your search terms should turn up much more material.  However, what you've already found may suffice as *the interface does not matter*.  Forwarding or bridging from/to an ethernet, wifi, or modem based (e.g., the sim7600) connection is done the same way.  For that reason I am closing the question, but if you need to ask anything more specific about specific details then please feel free.

Comment: Hi @Jarrr, you may try this setup [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/79866) and there look at the section *♦ Setting up an access point and with eth0, with NAT (recommended)*. This shows a connection using interface **eth0** but it should also work if you just replace it with interface **wwan0**. So it is important that you first setup the 4G connection what you already have done and then try the setup of the access point.

Comment: If you get some trouble then please open a new question but only reference these setup and ask what step exactly failed.

Comment: I got it working with your link @Ingo! thanks for all the help!